# Переделать регулярное-выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, excel, notepad++

Нужно удалить запятые только внутри кавычек "". Есть файл с множеством строк такого типа (First Name,Last Name,Company,"Head of Product Development, Casino",Email,Phone Numbers,Notes,Tags) Есть регулярное-выражение но там удаляется все что в кавычках "[^"]*"

Comment: Тут лучше воспользоваться PythonScript (если делать это в Notepad++) - `editor.rereplace(r'"[^"]+"', lambda x: x.group().replace(",", ""))`. Вообще, лучше воспользоваться нормальным языком программирования для этого (Perl, Python, C#, ...).

Comment: Спасибо! установил плагин PythonScript в notepad++ запустил регулярное выражение и все сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать своё регулярное выражение в скрипте PythonScript, где совпадение можно дополнительно обработать в лямбда-выражении.

- Установите [PythonScript](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%201.0.8.0)
- Щёлкните *Плагины* -> *Python Script* -> *New Script*
- Создайте файл `comma_removal.py`
- Добавьте в файл строку

---

```
editor.rereplace(r'"[^"]+"', lambda x: x.group().replace(",", ""))
```

---

Теперь можно запускать скрипт из меню *Плагины* -> *Python Script* -> *Scripts* -> *comma_removal*